# Ajax updating entire column when should update one table cell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I'm using AJAX with an upvote button. When a user clicks the button 'UpVote', the form for it should be submitted and the disabled button, 'Upvoted' should appear.

Right now the upvoting works, but when it does it changes every 'UpVote' button in the column to upvoted, then on page reloaded the buttons that were not upvoted return to the 'UpVote' button.(weird):

```
<% @master_songs.each do |master_song| %>
    <td><div id="upvote-form">
          <% unless current_user.up_voted_song?(master_song) %>
              <%= render 'upvote', :master_song => master_song %>
          <% else %>
              <%= render 'upvoted' %>
          <% end %>
        </div></td>
  <% end %>
```

song_up_votes.js.erb is this:

```
$("div#upvote-form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('fan_bases/upvoted')) %>")
```

and should change the above div for a single row not the whole column.

How can I fix this? Any hints/help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all of your divs have the same 'upvote-form' id. Therefore the selector "div#upvote-form" is selecting all of the upvote btns for replacement. Give each div a unique id and that should solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry if I was vague. I mean I have a table with a <% @master_songs.each do |master_song| %> block, so I cannot assign each div an ID.

Comment: Well it may not be the right solution to your problem, but it is easy to add a unique id in your situation - for example : @master_songs.each_with_index do |song, i| .... id = "upvote-form-#{i}"